# How to analyse the distribution of the noise being received by my RTL-SDR device?

Tags: receiver, rtl-sdr, noise

I'm very new to RTL-SDR and signal processing in general, but have managed to get my device (NOOELEC NESDR Mini) working and data into Python (via the pyRTLSDR library).

I am able to output a complex-valued array of predefined length. I understand these are the I/Q values. The distribution of these values is what I'm interested in for now (rather than applying FFT and whatever comes after).

In a given sample, I found that the distribution of both the real and the imaginary parts of the array formed a truncated normal:

[image]

I had some questions regarding this:

- How do I interpret the noise that is on top of these I/Q values?
- Why are the values truncated between -1 and 1? Is the limitation of being inside the unit circle just a hardware thing, or a theoretical thing?
- Can I extract *just* the noise from these values to get an array of true random numbers?

Further, can someone point me towards some literature so I better understand this initial step of the process?

Note that the SDR settings were left as default except the centre frequency, which is tuned to a local FM station:

```
# configure device
sdr.sample_rate = 2.048e6  # Hz
sdr.center_freq = 107.6e6  # Hz
sdr.freq_correction = 60   # PPM
sdr.gain = 'auto'
```

Comment: An RTL-SDR outputs 8-bit integer IQ values (0..255, or -128..127).  How are you (or the python library) scaling these integer IQ pairs to get a range of -1.0 to 1.0 ?

Comment: That graph looks like a *normal distribution* of noise, except for the two end-most bins, which are higher than their adjacent neighbours. That looks like signal clipping, where the SDR's ADC limits are exceeded, The usual procedure for "out-of-bounds" ADC samples is clipping. Could be the result of **auto** gain setting?

Comment: The auto gain setting on an R2832U RTL-SDR is often too high a gain (as it was likely designed for a different type and bandwidth of DTV signal).  Try using manual gain, and reduce it so as not to see any (or too much) clipping.

Comment: Hi Kris, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

An RTL-SDR outputs 8-bit integer IQ values via its USB connection data packet.  That creates a fixed limit to the range of possible values (0 to 255 unsigned, or -128 to 127 signed, not -1.0 to 1.0, unless scaled somewhere).

Your IQ signal will usually be a result of a mix of RF sources.  A significant portion of RF noise is additive (a smaller portion might be intermodulation artifacts, etc.).  Normally, you can't unmix an uncorrelated set of additive quantities, unless one of them (your FM station signal?) is perfectly known to you, and thus can be subtracted.  You could try filtering out your assumed-non-noise signals in the frequency domain, and then analyzing what's left.

Comment: Thanks. It does seem as though the `pyRTLSDR` library is normalising the samples. Suppose I tuned into a local radio station playing a song; how would I go about doing what you mentioned at the end? (i.e "filtering out your assumed-non-noise signals in the frequency domain")